# Execute python script inside a python script

Tags: python

I have a scenario where i want to dynamically generate a python script - inside my main python script - store it as a string and then when need be, execute this dynamically generated script from my main script.

Is this possible, if so how?

thanks

Comment: That script sounds very, very painful.

Comment: ... yo dawg ... http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/xzibit-yo-dawg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read up on the `execfile()` function.

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=exec#execfile

Answer (score 15):

For a script in a file use exec

For a script in a string use eval

### !!! **But** !!!

before you use strings passed in from an external source, sanity check them!
Otherwise you expose the ability to execute arbitrary code from 
within you program,
so **range check your variables!**

You do not ever want to be asking the question:

"excuse me mam, did you really name your son Robert'); DROP TABLE students; -- "?

If you dont understand the reference - see this quick cartoon...

http://xkcd.com/327/

but when you EVAL - you are taking full responsibility for the instructions that you are eval'ing.

Comment: Yes; check the input before eval'ing.  One suggestion: can you use less ALLCAPS and use e.g. bold formatting (or no formatting at all)?  It's somewhat hard to read the 'spaghetti post' with allcaps thrown in.

Comment: sorry for the "spaghetti post" I have gotten much better in later messages with formatting

Answer (score 1):

May want to look at the statement `exec`: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/exec.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute the script within the context of the main script, you might want to check `eval` [ http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#eval ]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how wise this is but isn't the [exec](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) function what you use if you need to execute Python code?

Answer (score 0):

There is precedence for what you are trying to do. The [collections.namedtuple](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/collections.py) function builds a template string which is passed to `exec` in order to build a dynamically defined class.

Answer (score 0):

As of Python version 3.11, `execfile` (which was the most convenient function) is not listed as built-in function anymore.

@George Lambert answer is the way to go. I'll add just some code for quick reference.

### Run script within script

To run the script "run_me.py" within the script "main.py" do this:

- run_me.py be like

```py
print("hello_world")
```

- main.py be like

```py
with open("run_me.py", "r") as fl:
  exec(fl.read())
```

### Run code contained in a string

To run the code contained in a string us `eval`:

- main.py be like

```py
string_w_py_code = "print('hello world')"
eval(string_w_py_code)
```